# How to resolve error importing CSV files into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database

I keep getting error messages while trying to import data into SQL Server.

What I have tried:

1. Used the 'suggest type' button under advanced
2. Changed the data type from `string[DT_STR]` to text stream `[DT_TEXT]`
3. Changed 'OutputColumn' of problematic columns to `VARCHAR 255` and 50

Below is the error message I keep getting:

> Error 0xc02020a1: Data Flow Task 1: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "start_station_name" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc020902a: Data Flow Task 1: The "Source - 2021_08_divvy_tripdata_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[start_station_name]" failed because truncation occurred, and the truncation row disposition on "Source - 2021_08_divvy_tripdata_csv.Outputs[Flat File Source Output].Columns[start_station_name]" specifies failure on truncation. A truncation error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0202092: Data Flow Task 1: An error occurred while processing file "C:\Users\USER\Downloads\divvy_trips_data\2021_08_divvy_tripdata.csv" on data row 1828.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
>
> Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on Source - 2021_08_divvy_tripdata_csv returned error code 0xC0202092.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
> (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 0):

It appears the destination column `start_station_name` is not large enough to hold the data from source, causing a truncation to occur.

You could change the data type in the destination table to nvarchar(max) and run the import again.  Assuming that is the only column with that issue it should import.